# How properly organize workspace in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, workspace, organization

Example: there are objects A and B. Object A must connect with object B (by Script) and object B must connect with object A (by Script).
How to do it more properly:

1. Create Scripts for each objects.
2. Create Empty Object and add one Script to it, and then in this Script to create two references (for A and B)?

Comment: Can you be more explicitly? do you mean communication between objects/classes?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this! I need to call some Methods and get some info

Comment: You shouln't call any other objects methods most of the time! if you do, your code base going to be a spaghetti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe at section 2 is known as `Mediator` pattern. You should definitely use it or you can also use `Observer` pattern. The difference between them is there's a mediator between them which causes loosely coupling.

The common part between them is whenever an event happens to the object itself, it throws a callback and the other objects gets notified and do their own jobs.

To even make a better organization you can look at MVC(S) and ECS architectural pattern.